# Whether the holographic universe of string theory prove the hypothesis of the holographic universe created by David Bohm or not?

Tags: black-holes, holographic-principle, hologram

Bohm, David (1980), Wholeness and the Implicate Order, London: Routledge, ISBN 0-7100-0971-2

As we can see from the book above, David created the hypothesis of the holopraphic universe in 1980.

And we can see from the words below,  the holographic universe of string theory is created in 1995.

Using this approach he has argued that near a black hole, quantum fields could be described by a theory in a lower dimension.[Stephens, C. R.; 't Hooft, G.; Whiting, B. F. (1994). "Black hole evaporation without information loss". Classical and Quantum Gravity 11 (3): 621] This led to introduction of the holographic principle by him and Leonard Susskind.[Susskind, L. (1995). "The world as a hologram". Journal of Mathematical Physics 36 (11): 6377–6371.]

So Whether the holographic universe of string theory prove the hypothesis of the holographic universe created by David Bohm or not?

Or what is the link or differences between them?

I have read the book of "The Elegant Universe" and the book of "The Fabric of the Cosmos:Spaca,Time, and the Texture of Reality", but Brian Greene doesn't mention about David Bohm.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I read Wholeness and implicate order a long time ago, but I believe that The "holographic universe" and the "holographic principle" are two different things with similar names. The "holographic universe" is more an idea or concept rather than a hypothesis and as such cannot be proved. That said I feel there is some broad conceptual overlap, but string theory is not my field. Maybe post a question like "What does principle mean in "Holographic principle":Is there a simple description of how string theorists use it in their work?

Comment: Then if you get a sensible response ask in a comment "Is there any  overlap with David Bohm's "Holographic universe".

Comment: I find no differences between the two "holographic universe" except the one of David is a hypothesis/idea/concept and the one of string theary is a hypothesis but is proved in some sense of math.Well,but I am not sure about this.... @baldrika

Comment: http://www.phys.huji.ac.il/~bekenste/Holographic_Univ.pdf @baldrik

Comment: I am not sure the "holographic principle" is mathematically proven, it's a statement about physics. It talks about the maximum entropy of a volume being related to it's surface area and about equivalence of physics on the surface in D-1 dimensions as in the volume. As I said I am not a string theorist. All I am suggesting is that you may need to reword your question to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The holographic nature of a theory is imprinted by hand as soon as the theory is quantised. That was the point David Bohm made. Quantum mechanics is inherently holographic. String theory is a quantum mechanical theory and is therefore also holographic. Possibly more related to your point is the string theory landscape that could potentially allow many different types of universe with different laws of physics. This could in some ways be related to the Bohm concepts of the implicate order - which is essentially infinite in complexity and enfolds different explicate orders (observable universes )